# Databricks Auto Loader creates strange subdirectories

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-autoloader

I am using Databricks' Auto Loader functionality to process JSON files from a directory and save them into a Delta table in another subdirectory.

My code looks like this:

```
transporters = (spark
.readStream
.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.format", "json") 
.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") 
.schema(transporters_schema)
.load(source_files_path)
.writeStream
.format("delta")
.outputMode("append")
.option("checkpointLocation", auto_loader_checkpoints_path)
.trigger(availableNow=True)
.start(target_table_path)
)
```

For some reason, the Delta tables contains hundreds of subdirectories containing Parquet files like the following:

```
01
|___
    part_00001_fsdgwsdg_afafafafa.snappy.parquet
    part_00002_fsdgwsdg_afafafafa.snappy.parquet
    part_00003_fsdgwsdg_afafafafa.snappy.parquet
02
03
0f
0J
0j
0K
0o
0R
...
```

I did not expect these subdirectories to appear. What could be causing them?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, it's not the Auto Loader, but the Delta Lake itself -  Auto Loader itself doesn't create directories with data.  Check that you don't have the `delta.randomizeFilePrefixes` property set to `true` on your Delta table.

See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/table-properties.html) for more details - it says:

> true for Delta Lake to generate a random prefix for a file path instead of partition information.
> For example, this may improve Amazon S3 performance when Delta Lake needs to send very high volumes of Amazon S3 calls to better partition across S3 servers.

Comment: `delta.randomizeFilePrefixes` may be activated automatically by column renaming via property `delta.columnMapping.mode`, see [Delta Table Properties](https://docs.delta.io/latest/table-properties.html). Strangely, I don't find the definition of `delta.randomizeFilePrefixes` anywhere in the delta code base at https://github.com/delta-io/delta. I only see test cases. Where can I see how the logic works.